# SharePoint 2010 header user control added > appearing on all forms?? help

Tags: branding

I added a user control in the master page for a particular site definition.

All good however the problem occurs when I open the dialog to add new documents for example.   The user control appears at the top of this dialog box as well.

This same top header is visible on all open dialog boxes at the top which obviously what i was going for.

How can I have the user header control only appear on main pages? (and not dialog windows?)

hmmm ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the control in a container div with the class "s4-notdlg", this will prevent it from showing up in modal dialog windows. You can read more [here](http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-2-custom-master.html).